# How to rewrite a modal CSS without affecting other modals in the project?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a loading component that I am importing on many pages in my project in that component I am using a modal, a modal that I have rewritten some of his CSS styles in a CSS file that I imported in the component
the problem that I have is that this CSS change of the modal effects other modals in my project
how can I let this CSS change only related to my component modal without affecting others

my loading component

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Modal} from "react-bootstrap";
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';
import './loading.css'



export default class Loading extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }




    render() {
        const {show} = this.props;
        return(
            <div >
                <Modal show={show}  className="loadingModal"  keyboard={false}>
                    <Modal.Body className="testtest">

                        <ReactLoading id="modale" type={"bubbles"} color={"#2f96a1"} height={120} width={120}  />

                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

my loading css:

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=00);
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 9%;
}

#modale{
    display: flex;
    justifyContent: 'center';
    margin: auto;
}

.testtest{
    flex: 1;
    alignItems: 'center';
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

Comment: The standard way to "extend" an elements CSS is: Give the modal an ID/class and write more specific CSS that targets that selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using CSS modules or such, I think the best way would be to respect the cascade and *always* assume that the css you import will spill. To do so I would encourage you to [use BEM model](http://getbem.com/introduction/). With it, it could be rewritten as:

```
            <div>
            <Modal show={show}  className="loading-modal modal--test"  keyboard={false}>
                <Modal.Body className="modal--test__body">

                    <ReactLoading id="modale" class="modal--test__content" type={"bubbles"} color={"#2f96a1"} height={120} width={120}  />

                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </div>
```

And for css:

```
.modal--test .modal-backdrop.in {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=00);
}
.modal--test .modal.in .modal-dialog {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 9%;
}

/* don't use ids for css */
.modal--test__content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: 'center';
    margin: auto;
}

.modal--test__body{
    flex: 1;
    alignItems: 'center';
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

Naturally, this doesn't follow BEM model exactly as it would require passing classes to the internal elements. Alternatively, for scoping, you can use [CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/).

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options:

- assign a unique ID for the Modal and change your CSS selectors to target elements with this ID only (recommended)
- use the `Modal.container` property to attach the modal to your Loading component rather than to the document body (discouraged if you do some tricky CSS styling, especially use `absolute` or `fixed` positioning of elements - this may mess up the Modal positioning logic)
- use the `Modal.bsPrefix` property to change the class names of the modal elements. Probably OK to do, even though the documentation states that this should be used only if absolutely necessary

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CSS-module](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

> According to the official [repo](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) CSS Modules are “CSS files in which all class names and animation names are scoped locally by default”.